# AXE-Core-Maven-Html is throwing RuntimeException: Error when removing sandbox from iframes in Selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium, axe

Software dependency versions used:

com.deque.html.axe-core : 4.0.0

Code that we have used:

File file = new File("src/main/resources/axe.min.js");

```
String path = file.getCanonicalPath();

AxeBuilder builder = new AxeBuilder();
 
String timeoutFilePath = "src/main/resources/axe.min.js";
 
FileAxeScriptProvider axeScriptProvider = new FileAxeScriptProvider(timeoutFilePath);
 
builder.setAxeScriptProvider(axeScriptProvider);
 
Results result = builder.analyze(driver);
 
List<Rule> violations = result.getViolations();
 
Assert.assertEquals(0, violations.size(), "No violations found");
```

Exception:

"java.lang.RuntimeException: Error when removing sandbox from iframes"

Can anyone please help us with this issue.

Comment: where are the driver calls?  It looks like they expect you to have already waited for frames to load. (no use of webdriverwaits when recursing through iframes in their analyze methods...)

Comment: Yes. We have created webdriver instance, passed same webdriver instance to analyze method. It would be good if you suggest any solution to resolve this issue. Can you please guide us how to reslove this issue.

Comment: did you go to a URL?

Comment: Yes I can able to navigate to application URL, Once the application launched we are passing driver instance to analyze method.

Comment: include your driver initialization and calls... (the order of these things will be important) and consider that the axe-code is not waiting for iframes to load.

Comment: final WebDriver driver = WebDriverUtils.getDriver();

UserDetailsPage detailsPage = new UserDetailsPage(driver, webSite, extentedReport).get();

   File file = new File("src/main/resources/axe.min.js");
   
   String path = file.getCanonicalPath();
   
   AxeBuilder builder = new AxeBuilder();
    
   FileAxeScriptProvider axeScriptProvider = new FileAxeScriptProvider(path);
    
   builder.setAxeScriptProvider(axeScriptProvider);
    
   Results result = builder.analyze(driver);
    
   List<Rule> violations = result.getViolations();

Please check here regarding the code

Comment: Post code in your question so we can take a look.  Include UserDetailsPage class and userdetails page markup.  The exception is occuring in parts of Axe code which check for iframes and parents... they are not using webdriverwaits on the iframes which could be problematic: https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core-maven-html/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/deque/html/axecore/extensions/WebDriverInjectorExtensions.java#L108